How can I get a nested user name attribute in Spring OAuth
I am using an OAuth provider which sadly doesn't have an endpoint for userinfo which you'd expect a /oauth/userinfo. Instead, they provide a resource at /api/me where I can see which user I am right now. The JSON response structured in a wrapper object like this:
{
  "data": {
    "username": "here goes the username",
    "email": "email@somewhere.net"
  },
  "meta": {
    "version": "api version and some other metadata"
  }
}

My application.properties contains a line which should specify the attribute with the username so Spring can detect which user this is:
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.my_auth_provider.user-name-attribute=email

However, this seems to only support items at the first level inside of the JSON object, which currently are data and meta.
I tried using different separator characters. These include the period ., comma ,, space  , greater than >, hyphen - and underscore _. None of them work. There is a GitHub-Issue which covers this issue and it seems to have been merged but I didn't saw anything in the source code.
How can I fix this? I cannot alter the response I get from the API.

What version of Spring Secrity do you use? The merge is into 6.3.0-M2. That's only a milestone, not an official release.

I didn't specify the exact version of spring security, however, I think I'm using Spring 3.2.4.

Spring 3.2.4 is more than 10 years old, see Spring Framework 3.2.4 Released. You have to update to the current version.

@dur he probably means Spring Boot 3.2.4 which uses Spring Framework 6+

Yes, I meant spring boot. I wasn't able to view my gradle file at the moment.

As of April 2024:
Warning: This solution requires you to use a milestone version of Spring Security which isn't in the default release
1. Update dependencies (build.gradle.kts)
Replace spring-boot-starter security dependencies with:
implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:6.3.0-M3")
implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:6.3.0-M3")
implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client:6.3.0-M3")

Add the Spring Security Milestone Repository to your repositories:
maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/milestone") }

2. Add Attribute Converter (SecurityConfiguration.kt)
@Bean
fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
    return http
        .authorizeHttpRequests { auth ->
            auth.requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
            auth.anyRequest().authenticated()
        }
        .oauth2Login { oauth2 ->
            oauth2.userInfoEndpoint {
                it.userService { request ->
                    val service = DefaultOAuth2UserService()
                    val converter = Converter<OAuth2UserRequest, Converter<Map<String, Any>, Map<String, Any>>> {
                        Converter { input ->
                            val data = input["data"] as Map<String, *>
                            val result = input.toMutableMap()
                            result["email"] = data["email"] as Any
                            result
                        }
                    }
                    service.setAttributesConverter(converter)
                    service.loadUser(request)
                }
            }
        }
        .build()
}

You need to get the desired user info attribute at the root level of your attributes. This function was introduced in Spring Security 6.3.0-M3, that's why when need this version or newer. Here is the corresponding source code in the Spring Security repository.
3. Update your application.properties
Finally, you have to rename your user-name-attribute to whatever you called your user attribute in the converter.
If anyone finds a better way of explaining, feel free to edit this post.
